# Floating Action Button Transparent above 5.0.1

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Android Floating Action button is working fine upto OS version 5.0.1. But it is not working properly rather its becoming transparent above OS version 5.0.1. Does any one have encountered with such issue. I have to change background Tint list dynamically so defining only in xml is not use full. So how to handle it with OS above 5.0.1. 
Thank you in advance for your co-operation.

Changing dynamically TintList color

```
 mFloatingActionButtonBack.setBackgroundTintList(changeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray)));
```

Xml for Floating Action Button

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contact_floating_btn"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/contact_directions"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gmap_frag"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        />
```

Style Part

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#d7d7d7</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you post your xml for FloatingActionButton?

Comment: @MukeshRana added now

Comment: can you also add styles.xml for both pre and post 5.0.1 version?

Comment: @MukeshRana added now

Comment: so is it the same for both values and values-21?

Comment: yes it is same for both

Comment: ideally it picks up the colorAccent for your FloatingActionButton, so if you still using a separate theme in values-21 , you should define the colorAccent color their as well. That the only thing I think you can miss, else everything is looking fine

Comment: @MukeshRana I sort the problem and thanks for your time I have posted the answer regarding this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found a solution to the problem I was facing is following.

```
  if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray)));
        } else {
            Fab.setBackgroundTintList(changeColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_gray)));
        }
```

and the method for `ColorStateList` is

```
 public ColorStateList changeColor(int color){
    ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_active},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_window_focused},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, //1
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, //2
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed} //3
            },
            new int[]{
                    color,
                    color,
                    color, //1
                    color, //2
                    color//3
            }
    );
    return myColorStateList;

}
```

Hope this will help someone else having same issue as I had